# Rxjs map and filter array- Return single object instead of array of one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter, rxjs

I have a method on my service that gets all Templates, and returns an Observable array of Template objects.  I am attempting to add a new method to my service that gets the array of Templates, but filters it to get a specific template by name, in an array.

Is there a way to get this to just return a single Template Observable, rather than an Observable Template array with one item?  I am still so new to rxjs syntax that I don't understand how to use things like reduce.

Here's my working method to get all templates.

```
 getAllTemplates(): Observable<Template[]>{
    const uri = this.baseService.rootTemplatesUri;
    return this.http.get<Template[]>(uri)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
      );
  }
```

Here's my attempt that is filtering by name, which returns an array with one element if there's a matching name:

```
getTemplateByName(name:string):Observable<Template[]>{
    const uri = this.baseService.rootTemplatesUri;
    return this.http.get<Template[]>(uri)
      .pipe(
        map(templates => {
          return templates.filter(template => {
            return template.Name === name;
          })
        }),
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
     );

  }
```

Is there a way to get a single Observable  returned by filtering this?

Comment: one option could be using `reduce` operator in rxjs, to receive an array and return single object

Comment: Where would I put the reduce?

Comment: Use `find` instead of `filter`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @JenniferS in `pipe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `map` RxJS operator is used, the returned observable has the type returned inside the `map` operator. The JavaScript `filter` method returns a new array as stated in [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). That's why your `getTemplateByName` method returns an observable of `Template[]` elements.

If you need to make the `getTemplateByName` method return an observable of `Template` elements, you need to return a single `Template` element inside your `map` operator. The JavaScript `find` method does this as stated in [Array​.prototype​.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Just use it to achieve the desired behavior.

```
getTemplateByName(name:string):Observable<Template>{
    const uri = this.baseService.rootTemplatesUri;
    return this.http.get<Template[]>(uri)
      .pipe(
        map(templates => {
          return templates.find(template => {
            return template.Name === name;
          })
        }),
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
     );

  }
```